# Button under keyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7

There is feature in WP7 - when I'm clicking on TextBox and keyboard appears, some buttons stay under the keyboard.

I want to realize such behavior in my application. How can I do this?

PS. ApplicationBar does not supports simple buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 events you want to be looking at

- [IsKeyboardPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.iskeyboardpresent%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
- [IsKeyboardDeployed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.iskeyboarddeployed%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
- [KeyboardDeployedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.keyboarddeployedchanged%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following blog post useful allows the movement between controls when using the Keyboard :-

http://mikehole.com/2011/01/12/wp7-text-boxes-onenter-my-1st-behaviour/

Hope this helps.

Paul Diston

Comment: It is not exactly what I want. I mean sopething like this http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2011/06/wp7-sliding-keyboard-swype-1308635955.jpg but with button instead of icons

Comment: The ApplicationBar only supports ApplicationBarButtons.